# Mysql Equal String returns 0 Rows and LIKE String returns 1 Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening! I have a MYSQL problem that I can't figure out...

Here's my situation:

```
Table Name: up_categorys

ID | Category
--------------
5  | Xbox Live
```

When I do this query, the database returns zero rows:

```
SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name = 'Xbox Live' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But when I do this query, the database returns 1 row:

```
SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name LIKE '%Xbox Live%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Maybe a genius can solve this? Maybe you!

Comment: Are you *sure* Row ID 5 is *exactly* 'Xbox Live' and doesn't have any spaces or anything before or after?

Comment: What about `SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name LIKE 'Xbox Live' LIMIT 0 , 30` or `SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name LIKE 'Xbox Live%' LIMIT 0 , 30` or `SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name LIKE '%Xbox Live' LIMIT 0 , 30`. Does any of these queries return something?

Comment: can you try to SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE TRIM(category_name) = 'Xbox Live'? what do you get?

Comment: I'd also try `SELECT length(category_name) FROM up_categorys WHERE category_name LIKE '%Xbox Live%'` to make sure the value has the expected 9 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have leading or trailing blanks in the category_name field.
Try

```
SELECT id FROM up_categorys WHERE TRIM(category_name) = 'Xbox Live' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: The problem was indeed the trailing blanks. Thanks for saving me 2 hours of my life ;-)!